# PHP form won't insert data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

For a while I have been trying to figure out php and mysql forms and how do they work. At this moment I'm stopped, becouse my code won't insert data into mysql database.

In my script allert I get an error

> "Sorry, there was an error!"

My code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['users'])!="")
{

}
include('../System/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $region = $_POST['region'];
 $country = $_POST['country'];
 $state = $_POST['state'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $surname = $_POST['surname'];
 $homepage = $_POST['homepage'];

 if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(Username, Password, Email, Region, Country, State, City, Name, Surname, Homepage) VALUES('$username', '$password', '$email', '$region', '$country', '$state', '$city', '$name', '$surname', '$homepage')"))
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('You have sucesfully registred your account!');</script>
        <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('Sorry, there was an error!');</script>
        <?php
 }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="login-form">
<form method="post">
<table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Username<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Region<select name="region" required><option value=''>Select one</option>
 <?php

include('/../System/config.php');

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Region_ID, Region_Name FROM Regions ORDER BY Region_Name"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $v['Region_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Region_Name'] ."</option>";

}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Country<select name="country" required><option value=''>Select one</option>
 <?php

include('/../System/config.php');

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Country_ID, Country_Name FROM Countries ORDER BY Country_Name"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";

}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
State<select name="state" required><option value=''>Select one</option>
 <?php

include('/../System/config.php');

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT State_ID, State_Name FROM States ORDER BY State_Name"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $v['State_ID'] ."'>" . $v['State_Name'] ."</option>";

}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
City<select name="city" required><option value=''>Select one</option>
 <?php

include('/../System/config.php');

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT City_ID, City_Name FROM Cities ORDER BY City_Name"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $v['City_ID'] ."'>" . $v['City_Name'] ."</option>";

}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Surname<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Homepage<input type="text" name="homepage" placeholder="Homepage" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="btn-signup">Register Account</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="users_login.php">Login</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how my database table looks:
[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Hello. Your script is really unsafe. Take a look at http://bobby-tables.com ... with this code, any user can delete your whole database in a few seconds, with only a bit of knowledge. You should use prepared statements. Also, stop using mysql_* functions, they are deprecated and no longer supported in PHP7. Use mysqli_* or PDO_* instead.

Comment: instead of just alerting that string, alert the actual error message with [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: @Twinfriends Thanks a lot. :) Will check it out.

Comment: You are also using deprecated mysql_ functions, use mysqli_ instead. Also, your script is open to mysql injections, you really want to change that!

Comment: @Cashbee Thanks, will check out this too. I'm newbie in this all and trying to match something together. Was looking in w3schools and tutorialspoint tutorials, but there was no much info.